# How to install old version of mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

This started happening today for absolutely no reason. Worked perfectly last week. I didn't touch the machine.

I have an issue described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309125/how-to-upgrade-or-downgrade-mongodb) and need to downgrade in order to be able to upgrade. Currently I'm not able to enter the shell as it exits with error #4

`need to upgrade database admin with pdfile version 4.22, new version: 4.5`

If I run it with `--upgrade` I get:

```
ERROR: error: exception cloning object in admin.system.users system.users entry must have either a 'pwd' field or a 'userSource' field, but not both obj:{ _id: "nod$
exception in initAndListen: 2 system.users entry must have either a 'pwd' field or a 'userSource' field, but not both, terminating
```

I'm trying `sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen=2.2.7`but it doesn't work because that version is missing - I dont know if there is any way to install legacy versions?

Can anyone direct me to a command I can use to install version 2.2.7?